# Behavior of const reference after casting to non-const

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, constants

I am somewhat confused about the following piece of code. How can **b** still reference **a** but have a different value?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int a = 5;
    const int &b = a;
    ++(int&)b;
    cout << a << endl;//returns 5
    cout << b << endl;//returns 6
    cout << "mem a:" << &a << endl; //returns 0x61ff18
    cout << "mem b:" << &b << endl; //returns 0x61ff18
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behavior is undefined.

You can legally cast const-ness away from a constant reference of a non-constant object; however, casting const-ness from a reference that references a real `const` leads to undefined behavior.

In this case, it appears that the compiler created a memory location to store `5` in order to provide you with a location to which to make a reference `b`, while variable `a` itself is optimized into a constant. Your code illegally modifies the location referenced by `b`, producing `6`, while the line

```
cout << a << endl;
```

is optimized into

```
cout << '5' << endl;
```

so it still produces a `5`.

Comment: You are right the compiler seems to replace the expression `a` with 5, so it's not really "undefined" after all. Thanks

Comment: @danwin Uh, yes, it is. That the compiler chose to do something which can be easily explained is irrelevant. It's still undefined behavior.

Comment: @danwin: The behaviour is undefined by the C++ ISO standard. That does not mean it's impossible to reason about the behaviour which the compiler has produced; it just means that you cannot reliably use C++ rules to reason about it.

Comment: Note that "undefined behavior" does not mean "something bad will happen". It **only** means that the C++ language definition does not tell you what the code does.

Answer (score 2):

Your C-style cast in this case is equivalent to a `const_cast`. And using `const_cast` to cast away the constness of something that was originally constant and then trying to modify it is **undefined behaviour**. All behaviour you have observed is to be considered random and is not required to make any sense.

---

You *can* use `const_cast` safely if the object was originally non-constant:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 5; // <--- non-constant
    const int &b = a;
    ++const_cast<int&>(b);
    std::cout << a << '\n'; // 6
    std::cout << b << '\n'; // 6
    std::cout << "mem a:" << &a << '\n';
    std::cout << "mem b:" << &b << '\n';
}
```

Comment: _"And using const_cast to cast away the constness of something that was originally constant is undefined behaviour"_ No, it's not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I first thought it was obvious anyway, but I guess you are right it could have easily been misunderstood the way it was originally phrased.